# Where to put my controllers for my API routes?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have the below registration that gets called in global.asax.cs in Application_Start.

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

Do I need to put my /api specific controllers in an area or as long as I inherit from ApiController it will just 'work'?
By work I mean my controllers will respond to the route path api/{controller}/ ...

Comment: Did you try it and see what happened?

Comment: Yes, but also... that^. Just do it and hit the path.

Answer (score -1):

Read [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx) to get a better clue.

Adding Routes to a Web Forms Application

In a Web Forms application, you create routes by using the MapPageRoute(String, String, String) method of the RouteCollection class. The MapPageRoute method creates a Route object and adds it to the RouteCollection object. You specify properties for the Route object in parameters that you pass to the MapPageRoute method.

Typically, you add routes in a method that is called from the handler for the Application_Start event in the Global.asax file. This approach makes sure that the routes are available when the application starts. It also enables you to call the method directly when you unit-test the application. If you want to call a method directly when you unit-test the application, the method that registers the routes must be static (Shared in Visual Basic) and must have a RouteCollection parameter.

The following example shows code from a Global.asax file that adds a Route object that defines two URL parameters named action and categoryName. URLs that have the specified pattern are directed to the physical page named Categories.aspx.

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}

public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.MapPageRoute("",
        "Category/{action}/{categoryName}",
        "~/categoriespage.aspx");
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.